# Pytest minimal working example: tests are collected but modules cannot be found. What is the best way to configure the test collection?

Tags: python, pytest

## Context

I am trying to test a project provided to me with someone else, but I am not sure how to go about it. I have boiled it down to the minimal working example shown in this question.

I have a project structured as follows:

```
.
├── Problem1
│   ├── p1.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test_p1.py
└── Problem2
    ├── p2.py
    └── tests
        └── test_p2.py
```

### Contents of p1.py

```
def add_two_numbers(x1, x2):
    return x1+x2
```

### Contents of test_p1.py

```
import pytest
from p1 import add_two_numbers

def test_add_two_numbers():
    assert add_two_numbers(1,2)==3
```

### Contents of p2.py

```
def subtract_two_numbers(x1,x2):
    return x1-x2
```

### Contents of test_p2.py

```
import pytest
from p2 import subtract_two_numbers

def test_subtract_two_numbers():
    assert subtract_two_numbers(5,2)==3
```

## Problem

Running `pytest` from within the `Problem1` or `Problem2` directory successfully collects and runs the tests contained within the `test_p1.py` or `test_p2.py`, respectively.

However, I am interested in running these tests directly from the root directory. This causes import problems and `pytest` fails:

```
=============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/awa5114/code/awa5114/example
plugins: dash-1.20.0, anyio-2.2.0
collected 0 items / 2 errors

===================================================================================== ERRORS ======================================================================================
___________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting Problem1/tests/test_p1.py ____________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/awa5114/code/awa5114/example/Problem1/tests/test_p1.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Problem1/tests/test_p1.py:2: in <module>
    from p1 import add_two_numbers
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p1'
___________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting Problem2/tests/test_p2.py ____________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/awa5114/code/awa5114/example/Problem2/tests/test_p2.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Problem2/tests/test_p2.py:2: in <module>
    from p2 import subtract_two_numbers
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p2'
============================================================================= short test summary info =============================================================================
ERROR Problem1/tests/test_p1.py
ERROR Problem2/tests/test_p2.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 2 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================================================ 2 errors in 0.07s ================================================================================
```

How can I run `pytest` from the root directory and yet ensure that the modules are found?

Comment: If you cannot change your code to use the root path as your project path, you have to add the different project paths to your Python path - either by adding them to the `PYTHON_PATH` env var, or adding them to `sys.path` in your test code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the problem is that your doing relative imports, like this:

```
from p1 import add_two_numbers
```

If you then run the `pytest` command from your root folder, `pytest` cannot find your module. Maybe absolute imports would solve your problem?

```
from Problem1.p1 import add_two_numbers
```

I use the same folder/project structure like you do and and I prefer absolute imports over relative. For me my approach works.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. When I modify the code in the way you describe it works. Do you know if the `__init__` files are strictly necessary?

Comment: @user32882 I don't think the __init__ files are necessary for pytest to find and and run the tests. I work in vscode currently and sometimes I also add __init__ files to my test folders, because the test regocnition of vscode is not working properly. But if I run pyest from command line, all tests are correctly recognized.